# React jsx variable to element inline style not working

Tags: reactjs, jsx

here my react code

```
const styles = {
  section: {
    paddingTop: '75px',
    paddingBottom: '3em',
  },
  loaderStyle: {
    zIndex: '999',
    height: '20em',
    width: '2em',
    overflow: 'show',
    margin: '12em auto auto auto',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
  },
};
return (
  <div styles={styles.section}>
    <div styles={styles.loaderStyle} /> .......
```

react render

```
<div styles="[object Object]">
 <div styles="[object Object]">
```

why style value is [Object Object] ? it's my wrong?
How to apply jsx variable to html style ?

Comment: Also you dont need that extra comma at the end of your loaderStyle object and outside the bracket also

Comment: @sjdm really? Thx u for tips i tried fix code for your answer

Comment: @sjdm Trailing commas in multi-line object and array literals are preferred by many people (and style guides), however, as they make for cleaner diffs.

Comment: @JordanRunning did not know that, always assumed it wasn't clean

Comment: @JordanRunning hum... so my code is right? no more need touch?

Comment: @Qfactor The trailing comma is perfectly valid syntax. Whether or not you should keep it is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @JordanRunning Thx u for answer! Have a good time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`style`](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style), not `styles`.

```
<div style={styles.section}>
  <div style={styles.loaderStyle}/>
```

Comment: a few min ago, awake to my problem Thx u for answer! Cheer!

Comment: @Qfactor If my answer solves your problem, please mark it as Accepted. Feel free to wait for other answers, though.

Comment: Yep I tried accept answer, but system said 10 min later available accept... wait for min..